# Did Anakin Skywalker have a genius IQ?

Tags: star-wars, the-phantom-menace

At the age of 8 Anakin Skywalker built his own Podracer as well as a Protocol Droid.

Is there any way to determine that, had he lived on Earth he would be tested to have a 'genius level IQ' (e.g. an IQ of 160 or more)?

Comment: I don't think there is any way to say for certain. He's certainly smart, but I've never seen anything that compares geniuses in the SW universe to ours.

Comment: IQ is by its nature a measurable phenomenon, and there are multiple methods of testing. Therefor, this isn't a matter of opinion and shouldn't be closed as such. No VTC from me.

Comment: I’ve got a canon answer for this (no specific numbers, but a general statement about Anakin being a genius). I’m voting to reopen on those grounds.

Comment: Any average kid today can build a flashlight today given few cells, wire and bulb. Can he be called genius in ancient Egypt?

Comment: Remember that the SW galaxy was far different from ours. Also it's supposed to be in the far past. So by that point in time in the SW galaxy, humanity may have evolved enough to make robotics/building podracers a "child's play" thing.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think it's unfair to use a model of IQ that we use currently for somebody in a fictional universe such as Star Wars.  In Star Wars robotics and complicated systems far beyond our own capabilities are commonplace, so just because he was able to build and repair stuff at a young age doesn't necessarily mean he is a genius.

Yes Anakin was smart for his age, but whether or not he has a Genius IQ of 160 in our world is really kind of indeterminable.

Comment: Agreed. Building a robot in the Star Wars setting could be as simple as Lego Mindstorm today.

Comment: Even for us, the average IQ **greatly** differs with the development state of the country the respective person lives in. Most of the African continent has a rather low average score in any non-adaptive IQ test due to the abysmal to non existant school system and extreme poverty prohibiting a proper education for a lot of people.

Answer (score 17):

The novelisation of Phantom Menace suggests that Anakin does possess a slightly higher than average intelligence as well as solid level of low cunning, largely as a result of his Jedi skills and status as slave to Watto;

- Watto trusts him to barter on his behalf for parts with the Jawas
- When negotiating with the Jawas, he secretly records their conversations so that C3P0 can catch their "unguarded remarks".
- Watto recognises Anakin's "gift for taking things apart and putting them back together and making them work better than they had before"
- Anakin himself realises that if he puts a casing on C3P0 it will become obvious that it's in working order and Watto will confiscate it
- Anakin builds a podracer out of scrap parts and, again keeps it a secret "smart enough to realise" that it will get taken by his master.

That said, nothing he does in any of the films or novels would suggest that he has a **genius level** IQ. Having an affinity for building machines doesn't by definition make you a genius, any more than constantly making ill-advised decisions makes you an idiot.

Comment: Excellently put. He is mechanically excellent and an outstanding pilot (the latter is probably due to his extremely high force affinity), an incredible swordsman (also due to the force), and a good friend and leader. However, none of these relate to *intelligence*

Comment: @SSumner's definition of "good friend": will try to chop off your head after murdering a templeful of younglings you helped raise; and being instrumental in fully destroying the entire world order you devoted your entire (celibate!) life to.

Comment: Well...not what I meant. But good spin on my comment ;)

Answer (score 6):

### Probably

Of course, whether Anakin would have a specific number<sup>1</sup> on an IQ test is nearly impossible to determine. **However, it seems likely that Anakin *was* a genius.**

Specifically, Bail Organa, who knew Anakin well, described both him and Padmé  as "prodigies," in connection with the possibility that Leia had inherited her parents’ intelligence:

> He risked a glance sideways to be sure his daughter was distracted by
> the fish and then opened the latest of his secret files. It was
> encrypted, of course, but he had it decoded soon enough. He looked
> sideways again. **The trouble with adopting the child of two prodigies
> was that there was a decent chance she would turn out to be unusually
> intelligent, as well. He was reasonably certain that Leia hadn’t
> learned to read while he was on Coruscant for the last senatorial
> session, but with her, he could never be sure.** He wouldn’t be able to
> keep her out of the mess forever, but he and Breha had agreed they
> should keep her clear of it at least until she could reliably speak in
> coherent sentences.
>
> <sub>*Ahsoka*</sub>

**There’s a pretty clear implication here that Anakin is at least “unusually intelligent.”**
Note that Bail was speculating about Leia’s ability to read when she was only a year or two old.

<sub>1: 130 on the Stanford-Binet, not 160, is usually considered the cutoff for being a genius, in a colloquial sense. Mensa has a requirement around here, for example. An IQ of 160 is significantly rarer.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I really do think Anakin is a genius. I know he doesn't do IQ tests like writing on paper or whatever, but **building a protocol droid and podracer** is really complicated. Not for Anakin! Although somewhat it's kind of fiction because of the so called "The Force" and says that he can predict the future (kind of) is a Jedi trait. But I would really like to see a child as young as 8 years old to be a pilot.

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE. While this does attempt to answer the question, we are looking for answers that some backup in canon sources rather than just opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from his adult choices he wasn't smart at all. Overvaluing his strenght at least two times, betraying his friends and wife. Not too smart, I would say.

Comment: That seems more like he was encompassed by rage and the lack of emotions he'd had for years. Building a Protocol Droid, his own Podracer etc. at age 8 seems pretty impressive.

Comment: Many geniuses make really shitty life choices. The unabomber did ground-breaking maths before embarking on a life of terrorism and murder

Comment: I have said this all along. We have a tendency to assume that he's a genius because he's the chief antagonist, but if you look at him objectively, he was constantly being outmaneuvered and manipulated by both sides. If you take off the mythic blinders, Anakin is a kind of person who was probably confused and frustrated by everything going on around him.